# Is it possible to implement a paging UIScrollView in both directions?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview

I want to implement a paging `UIScrollView` that will scroll in both directions (vertically, and horizontally). The default behaviour of UIScrollView is to be one, or the other. Not both.

Is it possible to implement a UIScrollView that would allow paging in both directions? For example, the user would be able to scroll left and up for the previous page with paging in UIScrollView, right and down for the next page.

I can use UIScrollView to implement scrolling horizontally with paging but I can't see how UIScrollView can be scrolled in both directions while paging. How could I implement this behaviour? UIScrollView ? or CAScrollLayer? or anything else?

Any suggestion are appreciated.

Comment: have you tried anything? Have you looked at any demo code? This is standard behaviour.

Comment: @Jessedc i can implement by uiscrollview to scroll by left and right. i have no idea how to implement four directions.

Comment: make your content size height higher than the scrollview bounds height and it will scroll vertically.

Comment: @Jessedc I don't think the uiscrollview can do the work.

Comment: Are you talking about paging? Or scrolling? You should update your question to be clearer.

Comment: @Jessedc i update my description. i means when scrolling, paging is also enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be talking about two different things here: scrolling and paging.

Scrolling is just flicking around to move the screen's viewport over a view that is larger than the screen itself. Normally you set this up by giving a `UIScrollView` a subview that is larger than it, and setting the `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize` to the size of the larger thing.

There's nothing magic about it. If `contentSize` is taller than the `UIScrollView`'s size, the scroll view will scroll vertically. If `contentSize` is wider, it will scroll horizontally. If `contentSize` is both taller and wider, then you'll scroll both vertically *and* horizontally.

Paging is a different matter. To know how to make it so "you can scroll left and up for the previous page", we'll need to know what a page looks like in your program, how it's represented, etc. From the small description you're giving, I think `UIScrollView` probably isn't the way to go. Instead, look into `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and some sort of animated transition between views?

But if that doesn't help, you'll need to give us some more details to work with.

Comment: what you said is right. I can use uiscrollview to implement scroll by left and right with paging. I don't think uiscrollview can be scrolled in four directions when paging.

Comment: If what I said answers your question, please consider marking it as the answer.